# How to get Intuit QB company id, agentid for QB Windows like in QB online getting by this url https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/rest/user/v2/<realmID>

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

How to get Intuit QB Company id, Agentid, LoginName for QB Windows
 like in QB online getting by this url 
https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/rest/user/v2/realmid

Comment: You would need to provide more details on what you are trying to do. Most of the fields you are trying to access are not necessary to access the customer data.

Answer (score 0):

None of that information is available from QuickBooks desktop via Intuit Data Services.

Some of that information isn't even applicable:

- Company ID - you don't need this, you have a realmID already from the OAuth/OpenID connection
- AgentID - not applicable
- LoginName - not available, and sometimes not applicable